# batch file bcp command

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, bcp

Stuck with a simple batch file that runs a bcp command.
I need this batch file to loop thru a txt file that contains the tables names.

Here is what I have so far

```
set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
echo hour=%hour%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
echo min=%min%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%
echo secs=%secs%

set year=%date:~-4%
echo year=%year%

set dt=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hour%%min%%secs%
set filename=%1
bcp TABLE.dbo.%1 OUT C:\temp\%filename%_%dt%.dat -n -T
```

I like the %1 come from input.txt file that might have 50 table names.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the problem? there are loops in sql and replace function... Can you read table names from .txt ?

Comment: Thank you for your really helpful comment. If I could have done it in SQL I would be done by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the locale/user settings dependent date/time variables but the
`wmic os get LocalDateTime` command which misses only the underscore between date and time.

```
@Echo off
For /f "delims=." %%A in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime^|find "."') do Set DT=%%A
for /f "delims=" %%F in (%1) do (
    bcp TABLE.dbo.%%F OUT "C:\temp\%%F_%DT:~0,8%_%DT:~8,6%.dat" -n -T
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `for` command to loop through a text file.  See `for /?` for help.

Let's say that the filename is `input.txt`, with one table name on each line.  You call it with `myscript.cmd input.txt`:

```
set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
echo hour=%hour%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
echo min=%min%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%
echo secs=%secs%

set year=%date:~-4%
echo year=%year%

set dt=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hour%%min%%secs%

for /f %%i in (%1) do (
    bcp TABLE.dbo.%%i OUT C:\temp\%%i_%dt%.dat -n -T
)
```